# Best Database to store small tables in one file-container

Tags: python, database, ms-access

I have a small relational database implemented on MS Access having 7-8 small tables (number of records in the largest table <1000). Nowadays I need to build new project based on this old DB implementation, and I want to find correct decision what is best DB to use.

The most disadvantage of MS Access is its poor VBA language and modules stored together with the DB data in one file with no possibility to be extracted and managed.

From other hand I am finding the decision to keep all data in one file (like it is done in MS Access – all DB data are contained in one .accdb file) very handy.

Thus, this is the list of requirements to such new DB:

1. To store tables in one file-container that can be passed to any
   person having Windows or Linux. This person should be able
   to browse this file using only easily accessible preinstalled
   software.
2. The IDE for this DB should have all basic UI friendly features that
   can be found in MS Access, namely:

   - Manage DB tables: creation, deletion, modification
   - Table relationship visual tool
   - Table browser/editor with ability to check relationship restrictions
   - Building and storing SQL queries
   - Optional: GUI forms designer
3. Programming languages:

   - Python
   - Optional: C++
   - Optional: Perl

What is the best Database I am looking for?

Answer (score 2):

[SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/index.html) might be what you're looking for.

Not sure what ORM you want to use in python but [SQLAlchemy](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/sqlite.html) supports it.